# Whether the permission value is allowed or not in the firebase database, app takes always to the same layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, here are some updates that I guess will explain the problem better:

I'm trying to do this following tasks with firebase database:

1. If email address of the user is verified, check whether the `Permission` value is `allow` or not in the firebase database `https://example.firebaseio.com/Users/Permission`
2. If `Permission: "allow"`, then make the `profileAllow` layout visible. Else, make the `profileVarified` layout visible.
3. If email is not verified, make `profileNotVarified` layout visible.

My problem is if the email of the user is not verified, it makes the `profileNotVarified` layout visible perfectly, but when the email is verified, the logic doesn't work. Whether the `Permission` value is `allow` or else, it doesn't make any layout visible. My guess is that it is not getting any value form the database. (I have tried making all the layouts visible or going to another activity for verified emails but it doesn't do anything. It just displays a blank layout).

This is my activity where I guess the problem is:

```
private void loadUserInformation() {
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
        Firebase AllUserPermission = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/Users/Permission");
        AllUserPermission.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String myStrign = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                if (myStrign.equals("allow")) {
                    profileAllow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profileVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    profileAllow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    profileVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
        });
    } else {
        profileAllow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        profileVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

For reference, I'm also attaching the xml and the database structure here as well.

This is my `activity_profile.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ProfileActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileNotVarified"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Not varified" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileVarified"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Varified" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileAllow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Allowed" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my database structure:
[image: database]

Comment: From the `new Firebase("https://smartpedi-rimikri.firebaseio.com/Users/Permission")` it seems you're using a Firebase SDK that is over two years old. I highly recommend updating to the latest version with instructions shown here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
if (user.isEmailVerified() && myStrign.equals("allow")) {
    profileVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    profileVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
private void loadUserInformation() {
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    Firebase AllUserPermission = new Firebase("https://smartpedi-rimikri.firebaseio.com").child("Users").child("Permission");
    AllUserPermission.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String myStrign = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            if (user.isEmailVerified() && myStrign.equals("allow")) {
                profileVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profileVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even after changing the code and also changing the Permission value in the database, the app still shows the `profileVarified` layout.

Comment: Also change `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and comment the else part and the `profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);` from the beginning of the if statement. You use the if statement only inside the `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: It still returns the same result. Would you mind updating the answer, maybe I've done it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the `profileVarified` and the `profileNotVarified` are different?

Comment: Yes, they are. If email is not verified, it shows the `profileNotVarified` layout perfectly.

Comment: In this case you need to change the logic of your code and use the if statement only inside the `onDataChange()` method like in my updated answer. There is no need to have extra conditions.

Comment: Even I tried opening a new activity in `else` section. But it still returns to the same `profileVarified` layout. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I guess the peroblem is somewhere else because even if I use `if (user.isEmailVerified() && myStrign.equals("allow")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
                }` it doesn't go to the new activity.

Comment: Have you tried to use this logic and to update the Firebase SDK to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still no response.

Comment: What do you mean trough no response?

Comment: I guess it's not getting any response from the database. Because I even have tried to go to another activity for all the logic if the email is verified, but it just displays the `profileVarified` layout.

Comment: It sounds that it's about another issue. The if statement logic I showed you, should work.

Comment: Can you please see the update of my code in my question that I've followed based on your answer? And it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are still using a very old version of Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
AllUserPermission.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String myStrign = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (myStrign.equals("allow")) {
                profileVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
            else {
                profileNotVarified.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profileVarified.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

       }
});
```

I hope this will help.